# There are these strange, accented numbers in my JSON file. What caused them, and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been working with Synaptic for Node.JS. I'm processing training data (strings) into numbers for the neural network to be trained on. Looking at the generated training data file, there are these weird numbers at the end of the file.

[the strange numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLxfw.png)

What are these, and how do I get rid of them?

I'm not sure why this is happening, but this is my code to create the training data file.

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Input and output file paths
const inputFile = 'Pre-Training Data/Complete Messages/politics.json';
const outputFile = 'Processed Training Data/Words/test-4.json';
const vocabularyFile = 'Processed Training Data/Words/vocabulary-test-4.json'; 

const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync(inputFile);
const Converter = dataBuffer;
const inputData = JSON.parse(Converter).join(' ').replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '');


const chunkSize = 100;
const chunks = inputData.match(new RegExp(`.{1,${chunkSize}}`, 'g'));

// Preprocess the data
const vocabulary = new Set();
const wordToIndex = {};
let index = 0;
console.log('Processed input data.');

// Process each chunk of data
const processedChunks = chunks.map((chunk) => {
  const words = chunk.toLowerCase().split(' ');

  words.forEach((word) => {
    if (!vocabulary.has(word)) {
      vocabulary.add(word);
      wordToIndex[word] = index;
      index++;
    }
  });

  
  const trainingData = words.map((word, i) => {
    const input = words.slice(0, i);
    const output = words.slice(1, i + 1);
    return {
      input: input.map((w) => wordToIndex[w]),
      output: output.map((w) => wordToIndex[w]),
    };
  });

  return trainingData;
});

const flattenedData = processedChunks.flat();

const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputFile);
writeStream.write(JSON.stringify(flattenedData));
writeStream.end();

const vocabularyArray = Array.from(vocabulary);
const vocabularyJson = JSON.stringify(vocabularyArray);
fs.writeFileSync(vocabularyFile, vocabularyJson, 'utf-8');

console.log('Training data processing complete.');
```

Comment: What tool are you using to display the file? If I had to guess, it's only the syntax highlighting and/or font rendering that acts up, not necessarily bad file contents. This might be caused either by the file being too long (you say it happens only towards the end of the file - maybe some floating point inaccuracies accumulating in the rendering) or by unusual unicode characters somewhere earlier in the file.